# Converting json object to json array using org.json.simple

Tags: java, json

I have one org.json.simple.JSONObject i.e {"2016":

```
obj =  {"12":{"19":{"12":"{\"DonationTime\":11111111111,\"Donation\":10}"}}}}
```

I want to convert to json array like

```
org.json.simple.JSONArray arr = obj.toJsonArray(obj); //no such method exists
```

Is there any method available to convert above object to array.

or do i need to iterate to make it `JSONArray`.

I am using `org.json.simple` not `org.json`.

Comment: "I want to convert to json array" - what does that mean? Do you want to transform the object at all? Do you simply want to wrap the value in an array?

Comment: yes i want to transform whole JSONObject to JSONArray

Comment: That does not clarify your question at all. You can't just arbitrarily turn an object into an array. They are very different data structures.

Comment: At least tell us what the transformed output you want for the given input.

Comment: something like ["2016": ["12":["19":["12":"remaining"]]]]

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to do this, but the answer is, yes, you will have to traverse the whole object to make the above data structure from what you have. Again, there is no magic "toArray" because that would be super arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

The String is a `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`.

```
String s = {"12":{"19":{"12":"{\"DonationTime\":11111111111,\"Donation\":10}"}}}}
```

You can use the following code:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(s);

JSONObject object = (JSONObject)obj;
```

Creating JSONArray:

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
list.add(object);
```

Comment: nope, this is just wrapping the value into an array

Comment: @deadpool: your string is not a jsonarray, cnt be converted to JSONArray.